# Jquery priority between two overlapping DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have two divs in a navigation bar Im making, and when the window is too small for all of the tabs, the rightmost one will stay on the screen, and the other tabs will slide behind it. All of the tabs have jquery .hover event listeners on them, and when the right tab is over the other tabs, the other tabs will fire instead of the right tab. I've tried reordering the html and the js, and neither made a difference.

Comment: Elements underneath should never fire. Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/f34Uf/

Comment: would you like to expand your question?

Comment: Might be able to try changing the z-index?

Comment: Giving them z-index fixed the problem. That doesn't explain by it was happening in the first place, but whatever.